# Adding Multiple Trend Lines - SSRS 2008R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to add multiple trend lines to this chart. See below.

http://imgur.com/cI4fnPr&bO4OkJo

This what I have currently. In this sample, there should be a Blue trend line and a Gold trend line. I cannot find any way to do this without removing the x-axis grouping. If I do that, then add a calculated series it averages the values as expected. I can then add the horizontal grouping back. However, that is only 1 trend line averaging ALL values. I need to to look only at one group.

http://imgur.com/cI4fnPr&bO4OkJo#1

This is what I would want it to look like.

Comment: I apologize I could not embed the images as I do not have enough rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Reporting Service, you can combine column chart and line chart.

See:
http://www.bidn.com/blogs/MikeDavis/ssis/361/ssrs-2008-column-chart-with-line

Comment: This will do it! Thank you!! For anyone referencing this as a soultion- I will have to combine the article linked with this one. 

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3432/add-a-linear-trendline-to-a-graph-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

I will do that calculation in my sproc and return the data points for the trend line. Then add that field as the source for my second value (the line).